# Selecting an appropriate graph of cubic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question asks me to select 2 graphs that fit the equation:

$y=-x^3+ax^2 +bx +c$ for some real numbers a, b,c

The graphs are shown below.[image]

The scale on the y axis of the left hand graphs are all by 1.

Knowing how the end behavior of cubic equations work, I know that the graph should have an "up-down" direction.  That is the left hand part of the graph should be in the up direction and the right hand side in the down direction.  This immediately makes graphs A, D and E the only appropriate graphs.

Also, knowing that $x^3$ graphs can have $0$ or $2$ extrema it would seem graph D could not work, since it appears to have $4$ local extrema.

Now, looking at graph A, it appears that the y-intercept is $7$.  On the actual paper it does show the number $7$ next to the intercept.  The $y$ scale values were accidently omitted.

Since I know that the value of $c=7$, then by the rational root theorem I know that if there are rational roots they would be factors of $7$.  Specifically, that means they would be 1 and/or $7$.  However, this graph looks to show a root at $x=6$ and since 6 is rational, it doesn't seem to work that it could have a value of $c=7$ and also a root of $6$.

Now, the issue is this analysis does not leave me with 2 correct graphs.  Am I not viewing this correctly?

Comment: In addition to the inapplicability of the rational root theorem to the general case where the coefficients are arbitrary reals (as pointed out in @Penguino's answer below), how do you know that the root is at x=6? It may look that way, but there is inherent uncertainty when drawing a graph: you don't have an infinitely thin pencil, so inferring that the graph passes *exactly* at 6 is fraught with peril.

Comment: My issue with graph A is that it shows one of the roots to be 6.  Since 6 is an integer and rational, wouldn't the constant term of the polynomial have to have 6 as a factor?  The constant term looks to be 7 and 6 is not a factor.

Comment: You are expected to reject D because it has too many local extrema.  A cubic will only have two, not four.

Comment: @user163862 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct the graphs which fit the equation are A and E but I don't understand your discussion about rational roots. You can decide the solution by the fact that the graph must be form "up to down" (for the $-x^3$ term) and with no more than two extrema points.

Comment: From graph A, it looks like one of the roots is 6.  Since 6 is an integer and thus rational, wouldn't that mean that the constant term of the polynomial MUST have 6 as a factor?

Comment: @user163862 it simply means that we have c=7 for A and c=6 for E

Answer (score 1):

The cubic has at most two extrema and due to the negative coefficient of the leading term, these must be a minimum then a maximum. Hence $A,E$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking it a bit. The first part of your argument is correct, leaving you with two possibilities (and they want two chosen - so you are already there). The rational root theorem is only relevant for integer coefficients, but you say they are real coefficients. Could be 4.2784635 or pi/2 or whatever. As is the usual case with multi-choice questions, once you have discarded the 'wrong' answers, the remaining ones are right.

Comment: But there are 3 graphs that show "up-down" characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

A negative $x^3$ graph will ALWAYS start at the top (because $-n^3\to\infty$ as $n\to-\infty$) and end up going down (because $-n^3\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$) after hitting $0$ (where it will hit a *point of inflection*) or $2$ turning points (or extrema as you refer to them). Thus the only two graphs which fit these criteria are graphs $A$ and $E$.